# My music discord bot doesnt work, he joins to vc but he dont play music

Tags: python

I am new in coding. I was doing music bot by YouTube. But when I am trying to play music, I get this error:  `ClientException: .pythonlibs\lib\python3.10\site-packages\discord.py-2.3.2.dist-info\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe was not found.` I downloaded ffmpeg, but i still get this error

Here is my code:

```
import nacl
from logging import INFO, info
import discord
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL


YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'worstaudio/bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'False', 'simulate': 'True', 'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio'}

FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

config = {
    'token': 'token here',
    'prefix': '!',
}

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config['prefix'], intents=discord.Intents.all())



@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
  vc = await ctx.message.author.voice.channel.connect()
  with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    if 'https://' in url:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    else:
      info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{url}", download=False)['entries'][0]
  link = info['formats'][0]['url']


  vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=".pythonlibs\\lib\\python3.10\\site-packages\\discord.py-2.3.2.dist-info\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe", source = link, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))



bot.run(config['token'])
```

I don't know how to fix it, help please.

Comment: Thanks, much better. Is the path to `ffmpeg.exe` correct? It's a relative path, so you need to check it from the folder where you run your code. You could try putting in an absolute path like `C:\\where\\ever\\ffmpeg.exe`.